# How do I subset a dataframe by criteria when some of the column are strings, and some in the same column integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called dc, with the column 'SEX' that is 92201 rows.

When I try to subset all the 1s, `dc1num=dc[dc['SEX']==1]` the new dataframe produces `len(dc1num)= 47614` rows.

When I try to subset all the 0s, `dc0num=dc[dc['SEX']==0]`, the new dataframe produces `len(dc0num)= 40492` rows.

When I try to subset as a string all the 1s, `dc1str=dc[dc['SEX']=='1'],` the new dataframe produces `len(dc1str)= 2130` rows.

When I try to subset as a string all the 0s, `dc0str=dc[dc['SEX']=='0'],` the new dataframe produces `len(dc0str)= 1965` rows.

They all add up to `47614+40492+2130+1965 = 92201` rows exactly, the same number in the original dataset. So obviously some of the ones are coded 1, some '1'; some of the zeroes are coded 0, some '0.'

I gather from this information that some rows in this dataframe column are coded as integers, and some as strings.

I want to subset all 1s and 0s, so that

```
len(dc1)= 49,744
```

and

```
len(dc0)= 47,614
```

I tried to make them all strings by `dc.SEX.apply(str0)` and then trying `dc1=dc[dc['SEX']=='1']` and `dc0=dc[dc['SEX']=='0']`, but this yielded the same result as before. Didn't do anything. How should I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
dc['SEX']=dc['SEX'].astype(int)
# or dc['SEX']=dc['SEX'].astype(float)
```

and then:

```
dc1num=dc[dc['SEX']==1]
dc0num=dc[dc['SEX']==0]
```

You can also do:

```
for i,group in df.groupby('SEX'):
    print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we can do one time conversion

```
df.SEX=pd.to_numeric(df.SEX)
```

Then we can split the df

```
df1=df.query('SEX==1')
df2=df.query('SEX==0')
```

Comment: @NelsonChung yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

To coerce the data to string format, try using the function below; the way you're calling apply doesn't work.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way that will work with non-integer like numbers:

```
df['SEX'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SEX'], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Convert all the values in the column to integer

df['col1']=df['col1'].astype(int)

```
        (OR)
```

import pandas as pd
df['col1']=pd.to_numeric(df['co11'])

**Solution 2:** Convert all the values in the column to string
Example : df['col1']=df.col1.apply(str)

One of the above solutions should work